# find shortest distance from origin to parabolic form

Tags: geometry

suppose that,we have given   following parabolic  arc
$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}$
we are trying to find shortest  distance from origin  to  this line, i think that if  we  rewrite it as $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}$, then

$y=a-2\sqrt{ax}-x$ or if we  rearrange  terms,we get  $y+a-\sqrt{ax}-x=0$
distance from origin $(0,0)$ to  line $Ax+by+c=0$  is equal
  $D=(A\cdot0+b\cdot0+c)/(\sqrt{A^2+b^2})$ so  in my case what   would be minimum distance?  please help me

Comment: Notice that $A$-$B$ looks different from $A-B$.  The latter is achieved by enclosing the whole thing within dollar signs so that the minus sign is set according to the standard typesetting conventions for minus signs.  Similarly if you want $\sqrt{ABCD}$, enclose "ABCD" within curly braces rather than writing $\sqrt(ABCD)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One asks that the vector $(x,y)$ is orthogonal to the tangent at $(x,y)$ of the curve. Thus, assume that $(x,y)$ and $(x+h,y+k)$ are on the curve and that $h,k\to0$. Then 
$$
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{y+k}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+h/x}+\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1+k/y}
$$
hence
$$
\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{y+k}=\sqrt{x}+h/(2\sqrt{x})+o(h)+\sqrt{y}+k/(2\sqrt{y})+o(k).
$$
In particular, $h/\sqrt{x}\sim-k/\sqrt{y}$ hence the tangent vector is $(\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{y})$.

The tangent is orthogonal to $(x,y)$ if and only if $x\sqrt{x}-y\sqrt{y}=0$, that is, $x=y$, that is $x=y=a/4$. The shortest distance is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt2a/4$.